# Replacing some characters in string JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I need to replace multiple characters in a string.
I have a line - "**123AB**"

And I need to replace the **A** at **%D1**, and **B** at **%D2**.

How do I do this? Can it be done with **.replace**, if so, how?

Comment: Yes, it can be done with `String.replace`. Read the API docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this replaces all the occurencies

```
var rep = function (s, search, replacement) { 
   while(s.indexOf(search) >= 0) 
       s = s.replace(search, replacement); 
   return s;
}
var s = rep("123AB", "A", "%D1");
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but you're duplicating work that `replace` can do for you

Comment: If global replace was necessary, you could have just done global replace ... `s.replace( /A/g, "%D1")`

Comment: @IlyaKharlamov This is the worst answer out of all the available ones

Comment: but you're using regular expressions.. they are slower than mine verification.. bad for you.. =\

Comment: You do realize that this is `O(n²)` where as regex will be `O(n)`? even if you didn't realize that, regex is 50 times faster here http://jsperf.com/replace-vs-on2

Comment: Esailija is probably the next jon skeet ! man your answers , comments are getting a Class!

Answer (score 5):

[`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is very simple

```
"ABCDEFA".replace(/A/g, "a") // outputs "aBCDEFa"
"ABCDEFB".replace(/B/g, "b") // outputs "AbCDEFb"
```

So you could use

```
"123AB".replace(/A/g, "%D1").replace(/B/g, "%D2");
```

However, you can do it in one pass by passing a replacement function instead of a string to replace

```
"123AB".replace(/A|B/g, function(match) {
     var repacements = {A: '%D1', B: '%D2'};
     return replacements[match];
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty straightforward, first argument is what you want to replace and second argument
is what you want to replace it with:

```
var str = "123AB";
str = str.replace( "A", "%D1" ).replace( "B", "%D2");
//str is now "123%D1%D2"
```

Comment: yes it does, it replaces *the* a and *the* b as op requested :I

Comment: @Esailija It only works for the input the OP requested, not if there are multiple As or Bs. `"123ABABAB".replace( "A", "%D1" ).replace( "B", "%D2");` outputs `"123%D1%D2ABAB"` You need the regular expression to make it a global replace

Comment: @JuanMendes [yes I know that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708779/replacing-some-characters-in-string-javascript/13708858#comment18827810_13708877), but the op asked for a simple replace that works for his input :-p

Comment: @Esailija That is a sample string, you can't assume that is the only possible input, can you?

Answer (score 0):

This should work  ..  `str.replace("A",D1)`